# Problems installing VTK on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, directory, make, special-characters

When i try to install VTK with command

```
ccmake .
```

I get these errors:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
 Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
 OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Wrapping
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/kwsys
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkzlib
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkjpeg
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkpng
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtktiff
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkexpat
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkfreetype
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtklibxml2
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/DICOMParser
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/MaterialLibrary
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtklibproj4
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/mrmpi
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/mrmpi/mpistubs
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/mrmpi/src
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/verdict
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtknetcdf
    used as include directory in directory /home/me/Masast/VTK/Utilities/vtkmetaio
.
.
.
```

I use my Ubuntu in Turkish, so my Desktop directory is named "Masaüstü". As you can see in errors it is used by ccmake as "Masast". My opinion is, this causes the problem but I'm not sure. Is it? Or is the problem originated from another reason? How can i solve this and install VTK succesfully?

**edit**
I moved the directory to home, but problem still exists.

```
CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   Common/CMakeLists.txt:555 (INCLUDE)



 CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   Filtering/CMakeLists.txt:396 (INCLUDE)



 CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   Imaging/CMakeLists.txt:184 (INCLUDE)



 CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   Graphics/CMakeLists.txt:363 (INCLUDE)



 CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   GenericFiltering/CMakeLists.txt:31 (INCLUDE)



 CMake Error at CMake/vtkWrapPythonSIP.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
   SIP_EXECUTABLE not set.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/KitCommonPythonWrapBlock.cmake:24 (VTK_CREATE_SIP_MODULE)
   CMake/KitCommonBlock.cmake:52 (INCLUDE)
   IO/CMakeLists.txt:457 (INCLUDE)
```

Comment: Why not just install with `sudo apt-get install libvtk` and tab-completing for the desired version?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sip-dev
```